# Where can I download the original android stock ROM[made by Google, without any modifications or bloatwares]?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I own a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 (N900). I am fed up of the bloatwares that Samsung has added. Also I am unable to get an OTA update to Android 6. I want the pure Android experience on my smartphone. I don't know, if there are different ROMs for different devices; but I have grown tired of Samsung TouchWiz UI and I just want the super fast Android Marshmallow. I couldn't find any website links for obtaining these ROM's. Any help regarding how to obtain the pure Google android ROM and intsall it would be great.

Comment: Questions asking for ROM are off-topic at Android Enthusiasts.

Answer (score 1):

The `.kdz` file you will flash to your phone includes **everything** in the phone: From system files to recovery, from kernel to libraries, everything. To flash a `.kdz` extention Stock ROM that is not specifically made for your phone will probably be the demise of your phone. **Never** fall for that mistake.

If you want to delete bloatware root your phone, and delete the app. You can do it with [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=tr). Very easy to use. But **beware of what your delete** for it might create problems in case of deleting something you shouldn't have deleted.